# How can I open port 127.0.0.1:8778

Tags: localhost, port, screen-scraping, server-side

I am running an application that uses screenscraper and I get the following error message:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8778
```

I have tried opening the port in Windows Firewall Advanced Setting - by going to:

```
Inbound Rules > New Rule > Port > Specific Local POrt : 8778 > Allow connection
```

but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

When I use netstat -an I can see 0.0.0.0:8778 but not 127.0.0.1:8778

and i ve tried http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and put in 8778 and it says:

```
Error: I could not see your service... Reason: Connection timed out.
```

The server I am on is WindowsServer2008R2.

Have i not opened the port properly or could their be another issue? I keep going round in circles with this.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This FAQ might help:

http://community.screen-scraper.com/FAQ/ServerRefusingConnections

If not, you might try posting to one of our forums:

http://community.screen-scraper.com/forum